# SCSI Drives to SATA for NAS Server

Tags: sata, scsi

I have a used server. It has SCSI drives. I want to repurpose it as a NAS server and I have WD Red Hard drives.

Is there a way for me to change SCSI drives with SATA?

Details

```
# dmidecode 2.10
SMBIOS 2.3 present.
73 structures occupying 2640 bytes.
Table at 0x000F1260.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 20 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Intel Corporation
    Version: SBR20.86B.0041.P01.0211111022   
    Release Date: 11/11/2002
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 1024 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        ESCD support is available
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        LS-120 boot is supported
        ATAPI Zip drive boot is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Function key-initiated network boot is supported

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 25 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Intel               
    Product Name:                                 
    Version:                
    Serial Number:                
    UUID: 
    Wake-up Type: 

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Intel     
    Product Name: SE7501BR2 
    Version: A95686-503     
    Serial Number: 

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 17 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Intel Corporation              
    Type: Rack Mount Chassis
    Lock: Not Present
    Version:                        
    Serial Number:                                
    Asset Tag:                                
    Boot-up State: Unknown
    Power Supply State: Unknown
    Thermal State: Unknown
    Security Status: Unknown
    OEM Information: 0x00000000

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPU 1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Xeon
    Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
    ID: 24 0F 00 00 FF FB EB 3F
    Signature: Type 0, Family 15, Model 2, Stepping 4
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (Fast floating-point save and restore)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Hyper-threading technology)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
    Version: Intel(R) XEON(TM) CPU 1.80GHz
    Voltage: 1.5 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 1800 MHz
    Current Speed: 1800 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: ZIF Socket
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0005
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0006
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 8 kB
    Maximum Size: 8 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 4-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2-cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 512 kB
    Maximum Size: 512 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: Fully Associative

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPU 2
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Xeon
    Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
    ID: 24 0F 00 00 FF FB EB 3F
    Signature: Type 0, Family 15, Model 2, Stepping 4
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (Fast floating-point save and restore)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Hyper-threading technology)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
    Version: Intel(R) XEON(TM) CPU 1.80GHz
    Voltage: 1.5 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 1800 MHz
    Current Speed: 1800 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: ZIF Socket
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0008
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0009
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 8 kB
    Maximum Size: 8 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 4-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2-cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 512 kB
    Maximum Size: 512 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: Fully Associative

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9A6
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB1-3
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J8A18
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: SERIAL A
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J7A28
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: LPT1
    External Connector Type: DB-25 female
    Port Type: Parallel Port ECP/EPP

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9A5
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: KBD/MS
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J7A6
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: VIDEO
    External Connector Type: DB-15 female
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5A16
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: NIC1
    External Connector Type: RJ-45
    Port Type: Network Port

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6A16
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: NIC2
    External Connector Type: RJ-45
    Port Type: Network Port

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1F1 - LVD SCSI
    Internal Connector Type: SSA SCSI
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4J7 - FDD
    Internal Connector Type: On Board Floppy
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2J5 - PRIMARY IDE
    Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1J24 - SECONDARY IDE
    Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5F1 - CPU2 FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J7F21 - CPU1 FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1H1 - SYSTEM JUMPERS 1
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4K1 - IPMB
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4J5 - HSBP B
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4K2 - HSBP A
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1B11 - SERIAL B
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1J2 - FRONT PANEL
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J7B11 - SYS FAN1
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J7B12 - SYS FAN2
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1K14 - SYS FAN3
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2K5 - SYS FAN4
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4K6 - SYS FAN5
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4K11 - SYS FAN6
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9B13 - MAIN PWR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1C4 - HDD LED
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1C3 - CHASS INT
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9B27 - AUX SIG
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4K10 - CPU 12V
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4J3 - USB4
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A7 - ICMB
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: SLOT1 (PCI-X 64/100)
    Type: 64-bit PCI-X
    Current Usage: Unknown
    Length: Long
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: SLOT2 (PCI-X 64/100)
    Type: 64-bit PCI-X
    Current Usage: Unknown
    Length: Long
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: SLOT3 (PCI-X 64/100)
    Type: 64-bit PCI-X
    Current Usage: Unknown
    Length: Long
    ID: 3
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: SLOT4 (PCI-X 64/100)
    Type: 64-bit PCI-X
    Current Usage: Unknown
    Length: Long
    ID: 4
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: SLOT5 (PCI 32/33)
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Short
    ID: 5
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: SLOT6 (PCI 32/33)
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 6
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description: ATI Rage XL IIC PCI::GR 4.332

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: SCSI Controller
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Adaptec AIC-7901X::4.10

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Intel 82550PM::4.0

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Intel 82540EM::1.1

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: HWID=02C9           
    String 2:  
    String 3:  
    String 4:  

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: POWER:power switch
    Option 2: RESET:reset switch
    Option 3: NMI:nmi switch
    Option 4: ID:id switch
    Option 5: J1H1:1-2 Normal Boot, 2-3 Clear CMOS
    Option 6: J1H1:5-6 Normal Boot, 6-7 Clear CMOS Password
    Option 7: J1H1:9-10 Normal Boot, 10-11 BIOS Recovery

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Installable Languages: 5
        en|US|iso8859-1
        es|ES|iso8859-1
        de|DE|iso8859-1
        it|IT|iso8859-1
        fr|FR|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0037
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 2
    Locator: DIMM1A
    Bank Locator: BANK1
    Type: DDR
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 266 MHz
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0037
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 2
    Locator: DIMM1B
    Bank Locator: BANK1
    Type: DDR
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 266 MHz
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0037
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 3
    Locator: DIMM2A
    Bank Locator: BANK2
    Type: DDR
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0037
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 3
    Locator: DIMM2B
    Bank Locator: BANK2
    Type: DDR
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x003C, DMI type 126, 23 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 126, 23 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x003E, DMI type 126, 23 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x003F, DMI type 126, 23 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0040, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 2 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0037
    Partition Width: 0

Handle 0x0041, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 2 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0038
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0040
    Partition Row Position: 1
    Interleave Position: 1
    Interleaved Data Depth: 2

Handle 0x0042, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 2 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0039
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0040
    Partition Row Position: 2
    Interleave Position: 2
    Interleaved Data Depth: 2

Handle 0x0043, DMI type 126, 19 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0044, DMI type 126, 19 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0045, DMI type 24, 5 bytes
Hardware Security
    Power-On Password Status: Disabled
    Keyboard Password Status: Disabled
    Administrator Password Status: Disabled
    Front Panel Reset Status: Not Implemented

Handle 0x0046, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0047, DMI type 38, 18 bytes
IPMI Device Information
    Interface Type: KCS (Keyboard Control Style)
    Specification Version: 1.5
    I2C Slave Address: 0x10
    NV Storage Device: Not Present
    Base Address: 0x0000000000000CA2 (I/O)
    Register Spacing: Successive Byte Boundaries
    Interrupt Polarity: Active High
    Interrupt Trigger Mode: Edge

Handle 0x0048, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Comment: eBay is full of cheap SCSI > SATA converters at about $£€ 5 each. Buy one & see if it works, before buying the whole lot.